# sbt, jetty and classpath

Tags: scala, jetty, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I'm trying to use the SBT with the xsbt-web-plugin.
Followed the instructions on the projects website but continue to get the following (sorry for the length)

```
sbt.JettyRunException: Jetty and its dependencies must be on the jetty classpath
    at sbt.JettyRunner.runError(WebApp.scala:72)
    at sbt.JettyRunner.apply(WebApp.scala:62)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.jettyRunAction(WebPlugin.scala:129)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$jettyRunAction$1.apply(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$jettyRunAction$1.apply(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.withCurrentRef(WebPlugin.scala:138)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.jettyRunAction(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$10.apply(WebPlugin.scala:141)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$10.apply(WebPlugin.scala:141)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:33)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:33)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:60)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:13)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(Main.scala:81)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runLogged$1.apply(Main.scala:75)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runLogged$1.apply(Main.scala:72)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(Main.scala:72)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(Main.scala:62)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:33)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:54)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:43)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:68)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:14)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:24)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:10)
    at sbt.JettyRunner.createRunner$1(WebApp.scala:45)
    at sbt.JettyRunner.runJetty$1(WebApp.scala:47)
    at sbt.JettyRunner.apply(WebApp.scala:57)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.jettyRunAction(WebPlugin.scala:129)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$jettyRunAction$1.apply(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$jettyRunAction$1.apply(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.withCurrentRef(WebPlugin.scala:138)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.jettyRunAction(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$10.apply(WebPlugin.scala:141)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$10.apply(WebPlugin.scala:141)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:33)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:33)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:60)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:13)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(Main.scala:81)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runLogged$1.apply(Main.scala:75)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runLogged$1.apply(Main.scala:72)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(Main.scala:72)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(Main.scala:62)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:33)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:54)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:43)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:68)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:14)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:24)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sbt.classpath.DualLoader.loadClass(DualLoader.scala:29)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sbt.classpath.LazyFrameworkLoader.doLoadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:122)
    at sbt.classpath.LoaderBase.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:21)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:10)
    at sbt.JettyRunner.createRunner$1(WebApp.scala:45)
    at sbt.JettyRunner.runJetty$1(WebApp.scala:47)
    at sbt.JettyRunner.apply(WebApp.scala:57)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.jettyRunAction(WebPlugin.scala:129)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$jettyRunAction$1.apply(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$jettyRunAction$1.apply(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.withCurrentRef(WebPlugin.scala:138)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$.jettyRunAction(WebPlugin.scala:133)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$10.apply(WebPlugin.scala:141)
    at com.github.siasia.WebPlugin$$anonfun$10.apply(WebPlugin.scala:141)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:33)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:33)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:60)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:13)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(Main.scala:86)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(Main.scala:81)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runLogged$1.apply(Main.scala:75)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runLogged$1.apply(Main.scala:72)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(Main.scala:72)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(Main.scala:62)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:33)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:54)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:43)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:68)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:14)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:24)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] sbt.JettyRunException: Jetty and its dependencies must be on the jetty classpath
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Here's my config:
In project/plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"    

addSbtPlugin("com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.1.2")

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.0.1.v20110908"
```

Here's my build.sbt:

```
name := "Project Manager"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

resolvers += "repo.codahale.com" at "http://repo.codahale.com"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.0.1",
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % "2.0.1",
    "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.4",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.2",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.0-801.jdbc4",
    "com.codahale" % "jerkson_2.9.1" % "0.4.2",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.0.1.v20110908"
)

seq(webSettings :_*)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you need to include jetty? val jettyServer = "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.0.1.v20110908"

Comment: Adding this dependency yields the same error

Comment: I've also switched to using basic configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the author of the plugin has missed adding the Jetty dependency in the [Usage](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin#Usage) section of the documentation. However, if you look in the [Running Lift](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin#Running%20Lift), you'll see that Jetty is an externally required dependency:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % "2.3" % "compile",
  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" % "jetty",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.26"
)
```

Comment: Adding the dependency to the project dependencies yield the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually related to the fact that jetty needs to be a dependency and that jetty 8 isn't yet supported.

The final config looks like this:

```
name := "Project Manager"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

resolvers += "repo.codahale.com" at "http://repo.codahale.com"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.0.1",
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % "2.0.1",
    "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.4",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.2",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.0-801.jdbc4",
    "com.codahale" % "jerkson_2.9.1" % "0.4.2",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "7.3.0.v20110203" % "jetty" // For Jetty 7
)

seq(webSettings :_*)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy all the lib and main class to the root directory of your jar/war and set the classpath to lib/*. Make sure lib contains all the jetty jars. This worked for me =>

java -cp myway;"lib/*" mainpackage.main